# RuntimeError: as_numpy_iterator() is not supported while tracing functions

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

while i was using function `as_numpy_iterator()` got error

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 image = get_image_data(image_paths)
>
> 1 frames
>   /tensorflow-2.1.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py
>   in as_numpy_iterator(self)
>       488     """
>       489     if not context.executing_eagerly():
>   --> 490       raise RuntimeError("as_numpy_iterator() is not supported while tracing "
>       491                          "functions")
>       492     for component_spec in nest.flatten(self.element_spec):
>
> RuntimeError: as_numpy_iterator() is not supported while tracing
>   functions

my code is

```
    # creating a function called get_dataset, which creates a dataset of image data from file paths.
def get_dataset(image_paths):
  filename_tensor = tf.constant(image_paths)
  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filename_tensor)
  def _map_fn(filename):
    return decode_image(filename=filename)
  return dataset.map(_map_fn)
#
def get_image_data(image_paths):
  dataset = get_dataset(image_paths)
  return list(dataset.as_numpy_iterator())
image = get_image_data(image_paths)
```

it throws error in using `dataset.as_numpy_iterator()` . I had used image paths of two array of filename

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible code to help us troubleshoot your problem?

Comment: sorry , I was using 1.0 tensorflow. I moved into pytorch now. But i do love tf.

Comment: Please make forum like pytorch does.

Answer (score 3):

The error message here is a bit confusing, since it talks about tracing functions, but I ran into this and realized it's a Dataset feature that's only supported when eager execution is enabled. It's enabled by default in TensorFlow 2.x, but but you can also manually enable it in later 1.x versions. If you enable it, this error message should disappear.